# Let $X_n,Y_n$ be two sequences of random variable, where $0<X_n<Y_n$. Does $Y_n=O_p(1)$ imply $X_n=O_p(1)?$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, statistics, solution-verification, conditional-probability

Let $X_n,Y_n$ be two sequences of random variable, where $0<X_n<Y_n$. Does $Y_n=O_p(1)$ imply $X_n=O_p(1)?$

**My proof**

Since $Y_n=O_p(1)$,
$$
(\forall \epsilon>0)(\exists k)\Big(P(|Y_n|>k)\leq \epsilon\Big)\ \ 
$$
Next, by law of total probability
$$
P(|X_n|>k)=\underbrace{P(|Y_n|>k)}_{\leq \epsilon}\underbrace{P(|X_n|>k|\ |Y_n|>k)}_{<1}+\underbrace{P(|Y_n|\leq k)}_{\geq 1-\epsilon }\underbrace{P(|X_n|>k|\ |Y_n|\leq k)}_{0}\leq \epsilon
$$
So the same $k$ works.

Is my proof correct? I will also accept any alternative proof (or counter proof) as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is correct. I think that you already saw the fact that if $A\subset B$, then $\mathbb P(A)\leqslant \mathbb P(B)$ (which is also a consequence of the law of total probability) hence applying this to $A=\left\{\lvert X_n\rvert>k\right\}$ and $B=\left\{\lvert Y_n\rvert>k\right\}$
would directly give that $\mathbb P\left(\left\{\lvert Y_n\rvert>k\right\}\right)<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you. My question would be how can you see that $\{|X_n|>k\}\subset \{|Y_n|>k\}$ just by looking at the problem.

Comment: @chuck If $|X_n| > k$, then $|Y_n| > k$ (since $|Y_n| > |X_n|$)